# How to change document root with Plesk 12

Tags: server, plesk

the default document root for my Plesk installation is:
    /var/www/vhosts//httpdocs/
How can i change this for one domain?
In Plesk 12 is no conf-Folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to change document root of the domain in Plesk control panel, please follow simple steps as below:

1) Login in the Plesk admin panel and go the domain control panel.
2) Click on Show Advance operations >  Website Scripting and Security which will take you to a new page.
3) Make the necessary changes in the document root and save the settings.

This will update all the configuration files related to the domain.

Comment: I could not find the referenced path to change the settings. I am using Windows Plesk 12+ latest. Any ideas?